# Parameterized query in ADO - add data into database

Tags: mysql, security, asp-classic, vbscript, ado

Bit of a newbie to vbscript, not particularly fond of it but my client uses it so I can't do much about it! I'm having trouble using parameterized queries to add data into the database! Please save me guys!!

So far, the existing code is

```
function ecaddupdateDEV (thistable, idvar, vararray)

 for each varname in vararray
    valstring = valstring & ", session(""" & varname & """)"
        thesefields = thesefields & ", " & varname
  next
    thesefields = idvar & thesefields
  valstring = " array( " & ecremovel(valstring, 2) & ")"
  vals = eval(valstring)

set temprs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

  if session(idvar) = 0 then
  'response.Write("chid is 0 add new record")
    ' ADD THIS REC
    temprs.open thistable, db,1,3,2
    temprs.AddNew vararray, vals
    ecaddupdateDEV = temprs(idvar)
    temprs.close 

    set temprs = ecquery("select " & idvar  & "  from " & thistable & " order by " & idvar & " desc ")
    ecaddupdateDEV = temprs(idvar) 
  else
    ' UPDATE THIS REC
    selectclause = "select " & thesefields & " from " & thistable & " where " & idvar & " = " & session(idvar)
    temprs.open selectclause, db ,1,3
    temprs.update vararray, vals
    ecaddupdateDEV = temprs(idvar)
    temprs.close
  end if
  set temprs = nothing
end function
```

The temprs variable I want to make parameterized for security purposes, obviously lol! I just have no clue how to do it! What I've read I just found confusing, please help!! Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a Recordset, use a Command. Here's the example, that will get you going, but you may have to tweak it, as from experience, named parameters don't really work, so you assign their value in the order in which they appear in the SQL statement.

[How To Call a Parameterized Query to an Access Database with ADO](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200190)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll definitely apply this and see how I go! Thank you again!!